# Crash stacktrace missing

Tags: android, google-analytics, stack-trace

I am using Google Analytics (newest version) in my app. Since I included it in project, I can't see uncaught exceptions in terminal, but I can in analytics console after a day. In other projects I can see stack trace normally by default.
I am using this code for handler in set up:

```
    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler myHandler = new ExceptionReporter(
            tracker,
            Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(),
            this);
    ExceptionReporter exceptionReporter = (ExceptionReporter) myHandler;
    exceptionReporter.setExceptionParser(new AnalyticsExceptionParser());
```

and AnalyticsExceptionParser is as recommended in set up:

```
public class AnalyticsExceptionParser implements ExceptionParser {

    public String getDescription(String p_thread, Throwable p_throwable) {
        return "Thread: " + p_thread + ", Exception: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(p_throwable);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what can be problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce this - could you have a filter on the log view by any chance?

Comment: Nope, like I said, on app without analytics it works fine.

Comment: Handled exceptions are shown in logs. (with e.printstacktrace)

Comment: It looks like the "Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()" call in your instance does not retrieve the default handler.  That's quite a conundrum.

Comment: Can I workaround it by implementing mine custom handler?

Comment: Most definitely, you can set your own default uncaught handler, that's exactly what GA does.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html for the documentation.   I'm just curious to know why this is happening, I haven't been able to reproduce it at all.

Comment: Funny thing, even with my custom handler I don't see stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem. I had these two lines of code after creating this new handler

```
ExceptionReporter exceptionReporter = (ExceptionReporter) myHandler;
exceptionReporter.setExceptionParser(new AnalyticsExceptionParser());
```

Somehow these two lines voided default handler which works fine without these two. I am not sure how will it affect exception reporting to GA.

Comment: That's really weird though.